# How to modify my CustLinkedList to implement insert more efficiently

Tags: c#, doubly-linked-list

I created a custom linked list on a whiteboard, for learning purposes.
`CustDoublyLinkedList` class with the nested `Node` class, but when it is time to insert, at the specified index method must loop through until it get to an index to insert. I want to insert directly without using loop as my `Add` or `PushFront` methods work.

I also added some more method like `IndexOf` and `Contain` methods for the list

```
CustDoublyLinkedList<int> myList = new();

myList.Add(12);
myList.Add(13);
myList.Add(14);
myList.Add(45);
myList.Add(28);
myList.Add(120);

myList.PushFront(32);
myList.Insert(3,1500);

for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(myList[i]);
}

class CustDoublyLinkedList<T>
{
    private class Node
    {
        public T Element { get; set; }
        public Node NextNode { get; set; }
        public Node PrevNode { get; set; }

        public Node(T data)
        {
            this.Element = data;
            this.PrevNode = null;
            this.NextNode = null;
        }

        public Node(T data, Node prevNode): this(data)
        {
            prevNode.NextNode = this;
        }

        public Node(T data, Node prevNode, Node nextNode) : this(data, prevNode)
        {
            nextNode.PrevNode = this;
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int counter;

    public CustDoublyLinkedList()
    {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        if (index == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("You Can Push with PushFront Method at Index: " + index);
        }

        if (index < 0 || index >= this.counter)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("invalid Index: " + index);
        }

        Node newNode = new(item);
        Node currentNode = this.head;

        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.NextNode;
        }

        newNode.NextNode = currentNode.NextNode;
        newNode.PrevNode = currentNode.PrevNode;
        currentNode.NextNode = newNode;

        this.counter++;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (this.head == null)
        {
            this.head = new(item);
            this.tail = this.head;
        }
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new(item, this.tail);
            this.tail = newNode;
        }

        this.counter++;
    }

    public void PushFront(T item)
    {
        Node newNode = new(item);
        newNode.NextNode = this.head;
        newNode.PrevNode = null;

        if(this.head != null)
        {
            this.head.PrevNode = newNode;
        }

        this.head = newNode;
        this.counter++;
    }

    public bool Contain(T item)
    {
        int index = IndexOf(item);
    
        if (index != -1)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        Node currentNode = this.head;
        int index = 0;

        while(currentNode != null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(currentNode.Element, item))
            {
                return index;
            }

            currentNode = currentNode.NextNode;
            index++;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.counter; }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= this.counter)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Invalid Index: " + index);
            }

            Node currentNode = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.NextNode;
            }

            return currentNode.Element;
        }
        set
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= this.counter)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Invalid Index: " + index);
            }

            Node currentNode = this.head;

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.NextNode;
            }

            currentNode.Element = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)

With this you can drive your insert requirement to O(log N) on average while still maintaining a linked list structure